# Preloading middleware / response cache in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I have some response values I'm caching using middleware in Laravel, like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $domain = parse_url($request->headers->get('origin'), PHP_URL_HOST);
    $key = 'request|'.$domain.'|dashboard';
    return cache()->rememberForever($key, function () use ($request, $next) {
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

If values within that response function change, I'd like to reset the cache, and ideally pre-set it before any user experiences the load time.

However I'm not entirely sure how to go about that given that I'm setting the cache value as a closure - `$next($request)`. Inherently, it is caching the actual serialized response.

Is there an easy way for me to mock this response programatically?

**Edit**: to clarify - the above functionality works fine, what I'd like is something like below:

```
public function resetCache($key)
{
    // Clear out old cache:
    cache()->forget($key);

    // Preload new cache:
    cache()->set($key, function ($request, $next) {
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Obviously the function above won't work since I have no context on `$request` or `$next`.

I'm starting to think I'm going about this the wrong way, inherently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $domain = parse_url($request->headers->get('origin'), PHP_URL_HOST);
    $key = 'request|'.$domain.'|dashboard';
    $response = $next($request);
    if($response !== Cache:get($key)) {
        Cache:forget($key);
    }

    return cache()->rememberForever($key, function () use ($reponse) {
        return $response;
    });
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I'm already clearing the cache value in a separate function. I will update my original post to be more clear.